# What is the delegate method that will called when closing an iPhone app by pressing (-) not the home button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, facebook

I'm developing an app and I have embedded facebook login in to that. I want to logout the user, when user closing the application after enter to the background, by pressing (-) not the home button. So I planned to calling the logout methods in the delegate method which called when application closing.  I was thought that it was `ApplicationWillTerminate` method. But it is not working. Does anyone know what is the delegate method or where should I called logout methods ?

Comment: We don't get one.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417003/applicationwillterminate-method-not-being-called.  Your app shouldn't need one; it should 'gracefully' transition from being active to being dead.

Comment: NO ! This is not the answer for my question. You have edited your comment after I vote up.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

}
```

Comment: These methods are calling, when I minimized the application by pressing the home button and other interruptions as well.

Answer (score 1):

set variable in info.plist  file
 Application does not run in background set yes 
like this

[image]

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
this method called when application enter background
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not the answer what I expected...